# Can a foreigner filing US taxes as resident claim Lifetime Learning credit?

Tags: united-states, credit, income-tax, non-resident

Since I am married to a US citizen, I can make an election to file my taxes as a resident.

Both me and my wife are graduate students and have been paying tuitions for 2012.

If we file MFJ, can both my wife and I claim the Lifetime Learning credit for tuition per person?

For 2012 I as a F1 student (non resident alien for IRS), but being married to a US citizen, I can make an election to file my taxes as a resident.

We have no other credits or deductions to make besides the standard and personal deductions

Comment: I edited the question title to make it less confusing. You're not asking about filing as IRS non-resident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you elect (or your wife, rather) to have you taxed as a US resident - then you can also get the credits.

Comment: so the LLC is "double" on our joint return? (since I paid at-least as much as she did for my own expenses)

Comment: Oh... yes:) if you otherwise qualify, that is. See here: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch03.html#en_US_2012_publink1000178154